# Why is the output in these constructs different in java's file handling's read() function?

Tags: java, file-handling

If read() is written and assigned inside while it runs fine.

```
while((ch=fr.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print((char)ch);
        }

Output: This is a text.
```

But if its used outside it gives kind of an encrypted output

```
while(fr.read()!=-1){
            ch=fr.read();
            System.out.print((char)ch);
        }

Output: hsi et?
```

What is the reason behind this behaviour ?

Comment: Reading once != reading twice.  Your "kind of encrypted" output is simply every other letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**read()** method reads one character and moves the cursor to next character.

In first `while` loop you are reading once but in second loop, you are reading twice. So if in a file, there is only character then first loop will print that character while second loop will reach the end of file after first statement in condition block and hence the line `ch=fr.read();` will return -1.